# Javascript - como efetuar uma busca por uma propriedade em um objeto de uma (array)?

Tags: javascript

Olá, estou aprendendo JavaScript e necessito efetuar uma busca por uma propriedade (cidade) em um objeto de uma array(markersData), e se o termo buscado existir, ai mostrar todo o conteúdo do objeto.

exemplo:

```
var markersData = [
   {
      cidade: "Aceguá",
      empresa: "Empresa: JOÃO EVARISTO CASSANEGO MACHADO",
      representante: "Representante: Evaristo",
      telefone: "Fone: (51) 98149 9986",
      email: "Email: <a href='mailto:machadoevaristo25@hotmail.com'>machadoevaristo25@hotmail.com</a>" 
   },
   {
      cidade: "Água Santa",
      empresa: "Empresa: A. ROBERTO SEVERO REPRES COM",
      representante: "Representante: Roberto",
      telefone: "Fone: (54) 99133 2034",
      email: "Email: <a href='mailto:betosevero@bol.com.br'>betosevero@bol.com.br</a>" 
   }
}
```

Comment: Queres encontrar o primeiro objeto ou filtrar a array  e criar uma nova com esses objetos? Podes explicar melhor como mais usar esses dados?

Comment: Olá Sérgio, eu quero usar um input para o usuário digitar o nome da cidade, se esta cidade existir  dentro dos objetos da array, ai quero mostrar todo o conteúdo no objeto no html como resultado

Comment: E se houver 3 objetos com essa cidade?

Comment: não haverão 3 objetos com a mesma string para cidade, ali no exemplo coloquei a array com dois objetos (duas cidades) certo? a array original terá dezenas ou até centenas de objetos.... espero estar sendo correto nos termos...

então, o usuário deverá efetuar a busca digitando o nome da cidade (string) no input, se este nome (propriedade cidade) existir dentro da array, então deverá mostrar no innerHtml todos os dados guardados no objeto em questão (cidade, empresa, representante, telefone e email.

Comment: Ok, e queres match completo ou escrevendo `santa` devem aparecer `Água Santa` e uma cidade (se houver) `Santa Ana` também?

Comment: eu havia pensado em colocar o match exato, mas se você puder me mostrar duas opções seria ótimo, seriam dois aprendizados em uma necessidade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deixo um exemplo onde invento e simplifico as partes que não sei como queres implementar:

```js
const markersData = [{
    cidade: 'Aceguá',
    empresa: 'Empresa: JOÃO EVARISTO CASSANEGO MACHADO',
    representante: 'Representante: Evaristo',
    telefone: 'Fone: (51) 98149 9986',
    email: "Email: <a href='mailto:machadoevaristo25@hotmail.com'>machadoevaristo25@hotmail.com</a>",
  },
  {
    cidade: 'Água Santa',
    empresa: 'Empresa: A. ROBERTO SEVERO REPRES COM',
    representante: 'Representante: Roberto',
    telefone: 'Fone: (54) 99133 2034',
    email: "Email: <a href='mailto:betosevero@bol.com.br'>betosevero@bol.com.br</a>",
  },
];

const mostrador = document.getElementById('mostrador');
const procura = document.getElementById('procura');
procura.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  const filtrados = markersData.filter((marker) => {
    const txt = e.target.value;
    // versão simples seria:
    // return txt && (txt === marker.cidade);

    // versão mais flexivel:
    return marker.cidade.toLowerCase().includes(txt.toLowerCase());
  });

  mostrador.innerHTML = filtrados.map(
    (obj) => `
    <h4>${obj.cidade}</h4>
    <p>${obj.empresa}</p>
  `,
  ).join('<hr/>');
});
```

```html
<input id="procura" />
<div id="mostrador"></div>
```

A parte essencial é `marker.cidade.toLowerCase().includes(txt.toLowerCase());` o que faço é comparar o texto procurado `txt` em letras pequenas dentro do nome de cada cidade (também em letra pequena). Esta procura não leva em conta acentos, há outras perguntas que abordam essa problemática, mas penso não ser esse o problema principal da pergunta.

Com um botão de submit ficaria assim:

```js
const markersData = [{
    cidade: 'Aceguá',
    empresa: 'Empresa: JOÃO EVARISTO CASSANEGO MACHADO',
    representante: 'Representante: Evaristo',
    telefone: 'Fone: (51) 98149 9986',
    email: "Email: <a href='mailto:machadoevaristo25@hotmail.com'>machadoevaristo25@hotmail.com</a>",
  },
  {
    cidade: 'Água Santa',
    empresa: 'Empresa: A. ROBERTO SEVERO REPRES COM',
    representante: 'Representante: Roberto',
    telefone: 'Fone: (54) 99133 2034',
    email: "Email: <a href='mailto:betosevero@bol.com.br'>betosevero@bol.com.br</a>",
  },
];

const mostrador = document.getElementById('mostrador');
const enviar = document.getElementById('enviar');
const procura = document.getElementById('procura');
enviar.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const filtrados = markersData.filter((marker) => {
    const txt = procura.value;
    // versão simples seria:
    // return txt && (txt === marker.cidade);

    // versão mais flexivel:
    return marker.cidade.toLowerCase().includes(txt.toLowerCase());
  });

  mostrador.innerHTML = filtrados.map(
    (obj) => `
    <h4>${obj.cidade}</h4>
    <p>${obj.empresa}</p>
  `,
  ).join('<hr/>');
});
```

```html
<input id="procura" /><button id="enviar" type="button">Enviar</button>
<div id="mostrador"></div>
```

Comment: entendi, então talvez neste caso seria mais apropriado o uso de um select com o nome de todas as cidades? isso eliminaria o problema da acentuação?

Comment: @RafaKunz sim, sem dúvida, Podes também ter um select customizado com funcionalidade de procura.

Comment: ♦ mais uma vez obrigado pela sua ajuda! tenho mais uma dúvida, ao invés de utilizar 'keyup', eu gostaria de utilizar um input button com 'submit', tentei substituir no cógigo acima, mas não funcionou aenas alterando o keyup por submit com um input type='submit', você poderia me ajudar?

Comment: @RafaKunz juntei essa variante à resposta. Se a pergunta responde ao que procuras podes clicar para marcar como aceite.